# excel- what formula would for blank cell to use different cell data

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula to always use the cell above if the cell below is blank. If the blank cell is then filled out I will need the statement to jump to the next cell below it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data is layed out as per the image below and your want your formula to go in the yellow cell.  You want the last entry in the cells below, and you want the data from the cell above if there are no entries below.

[image: Layout]

The sticky part of this solution in that it uses a function that performs array like calculations.  As such you should not use full column references.  Without knowing what you data layout is it makes it difficult to automate a few things.  For this particular solution I am assuming you will not have any other information below the yellow cells other than certificates.  I have also assumed you wont have any certificates added past row 20.  Feel free to adjust this number to suit your needs, however avoid full column references within AGGREGATE as you will be performing a bunch of useless calculations on empty cells that can bog down your system.

Used the following formula in the yellow cell B3 then copy to D4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(B4:B20)/(B4:B20<>""),1)),B2)
```

[image: POC]

Comment: I would like it to continuously jump to the next cell below it. So indefinitely. If that makes sense.

Comment: So my specific situation is, I have a certification sheet that is pulling from a log. I always want the certification sheet to display and populate the most recent log information. The log sheet is always being added to so i will need the certification to jump to the next cell below it.

Comment: let me rephrase.  You want to cell of above if there is no certificate, but if there is a certificate below, you want the last one in the column?

Comment: @ChrissyHinkle updated answer based on new understanding